# ExtJS3 QuickTips not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs3, qtip

Have trouble with IE9 and ExtJS3 Grid + quickTips. 
Tooltips not shows on headers mouseover in IE9
In other browsers - its all ok, shows well. Problem only with IE9.

I use this to init quicktips:

```
Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = "js/ext-3.3.1/resources/images/default/s.gif";
Ext.QuickTips.init();[/CODE]
```

And this:

```
cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults: {
        sortable: true, // columns are not sortable by default          
        menuDisabled: true
    },
    columns: [

        {
           tooltip: "Id is here<br />And second line",
            header: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            width: 50
        },
```

Here is this test app:
http://softm.org.ua/projects/extjs3quicktips/admin.php

Yor can see, tooltips shows in FF as ex, and not shows in IE9.

Pls help me to show QuckTips in ExtJS grid in IE0
Seems this is css issue, but i cant define what exactly happens

PS. Suddenly i noticed that QuckTips+ExtJS3 grid works well in Ie9 but inside fancybox iframe.
Here is example  : http://softm.org.ua/quicktips-of-extjs-not-working-in-ie9-another-one-extjs3-issue-to-resolve/

Answer (score 0):

I not find what was matter of issue, but fix this. Answer is [here](http://softm.org.ua/quicktips-of-extjs-not-working-in-ie9-another-one-extjs3-issue-to-resolve/). I simply force IE in IE8 compatible mode. Thats all, it will start working.